# Save response from redis (redis2 nginx module) to nginx variable

Tags: perl, nginx, redis

I want to create a small web app just for fun.
App will using only nginx (and its modules), several html pages with  ssi and redis.
Nginx building with embedded perl module, [redis2 module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRedis2Module) and some other modules.

**Question:**
How to save a response from redis to nginx variable (redis2 module response raw TCP)?

(I know about [lua module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule), but I don't want to use is).
It is possible to cache to cache raw TCP response from redis2 module? Perhaps I should use perl for it?